# "We go there every year." Is this correct or it should be "we go there on every year"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

"We go there every year." Is this correct or it should be "we go there on every year"?

Comment: "We go there every year" is grammatical. Noun phrases headed by the word "year" can be used adverbially without any preposition (according to one terminolgical system, "every year" is a "[bare NP adverb of time](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/432263/77227)").

Comment: Similar questions: [What is the difference between “in this year” and “this year”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/282858), [“In this year” versus “this year”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25279)